# Probability of defective items: probability approximation

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

It is known that any item produced by a certain machine will be defective with
probability $0.01$, independently of any other item.

What is the probability that a lot of $100$ items will contain more than $2$ defective items? You should use a suitable approximation and state the parameter values.

Comment: What type of probability distributions are you familiar with? Notice that the probability of success ( p = .01) is constant and it's either "defective" or "non-defective", does that ring any bells as to which distribution to use ?

Comment: Let me suggest that you stop using the site to externalize your homework. Or, indicate the name of the university you are studying at and the name of the TA responsible of the relevant teaching unit. Deal?

Comment: This is not my homework. I am preparing for an exam and I thought it would be a good idea to see if I could get the answers for some exercises that I don't know how to do...

Comment: No, it is **YOU** who "should use a suitable approximation and state the parameter values". We might be willing to help you once you do that!!!

Answer (score 1):

We know

$$p = .01$$
$$n = 100$$

And our interest is
$$x > 2$$

I would use the binomial distribution because the probability of success ( p = .01) is constant and the item is either "defective" or "non-defective". You're interested in:

$$P(x>2)=P (x\geq 2.5)=P (x\geq 3)$$

You can estimate this binomial distribution using the Poisson approximation, because we have very large $n$ and very small $p$, The parameters are:
$$n*p = 1$$

For a poison distribution we know that:

$$P(x) =\frac{e^{-\text{np}} \text{np}^x}{x!}$$

Thus,

$$P (x > 2)\approx \frac{\frac{1}{e}*1^x}{x!}$$
$$1-P (x\leq 2)\approx\frac{\frac{1}{e}*1^x}{x!}$$
$$ P (x\leq 2)\approx 1-(1/e\left(\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{1!}+1\right))$$

```
 1-ppois(2,1)
 = .0803
```

Much thanks and appreciation to David Quinn for giving me some clarification, I hope I did this correctly for you.

**In addition, you can use "PoissonCDF" in a graphine calculator and doing *1 - probability*, where parameters Lambda = 1, lower bound = 0 and upper bound = 2. Doing so, 1 - .919699 = .0803 which matches the results produced in the R code above.**

Comment: You're using the wrong approximation method.

Comment: Why don't you amend your answer and use the Poisson Distribution instead? This is clearly what was intended by the question.

Comment: I would love to but I really don't see how this follows a Poisson Distribution

Comment: It's a Binomial Distribution, sure enough, but use the Poisson distribution as an approximation, not the Normal Distribution

Comment: @DavidQuinn How about now? I hope I did it correctly. Thanks for helping me out, you should be the one receiving reputation points for this

Comment: The last step is $p(X\leq 2)=1-e^{-1}(1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!})$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49568/discussion-between-brandon-and-david-quinn).

Comment: I agree that the question's wording *maybe* points to Poisson. But why not solve it exactly by using $1 - (P(x=0) + P(x=1) + P(x=2)) \approx 0.0794$ This seems more straightforward and a more accurate solution. Of course without knowing where the exercise was taken from, it's hard to guess about its rationale.

Comment: @Thanassis I had the same intentions at first. I used 1-pbinom(2, 100, .01) and got .0794 (like you did), then 1-ppois(2,1) and got .0803. While the probabilities are very close, I was suggested by David to use Poisson, though I wasn't exactly sure why and I am still not too sure, other than the fact that Poisson should be used to approximate binomial when there is  large sample and small probability of success . If I was to make a research paper on this or something, I would just report both methods

Comment: If you were making a research paper you should have only reported the binomial result (because it's straightforward and accurate) unless you want to introduce Poisson approximations later in the paper for some reason. For the specific question, I agree that using Poisson might be one of the goals of this exercise, but there are other interpretations of "suitable approximation". We simply don't have enough insight into the exercise's goals. @DavidQuinn I wonder why you seemed so certain that Poisson should be used?

Answer (score 0):

*Comment:* Here are some computations in R: You might as well review several topics for your
upcoming exam. You might include in your review any rules of thumb in your text for using various approximations.

**Binomial.** Let $X \sim Binom(100, .01).$ You seek $P(X > 2) = 1 - P(X \le 2).$

```
1 - pbinom(2, 100, .01)
## 0.0793732
```

**Poisson.** But you were asked to use a 'suitable approximation'.
From the binomial the mean is $\mu = np = 100(.01) = 1.$
Let $Y \sim Pois(1).$  You seek $P(Y > 2).$

```
1 - ppois(2, 1)
## 0.0803014
```

**Normal.** The only other common approximation to binomial in elementary
courses is the normal. Most of the guidelines for using the normal
approximation are violated here. But let's try it. As above, $m = 1.$ Also,
 $\sigma^2 = np(1-p) = .99,$ so $\sigma =  0.995.$

Let $W \sim Norm(1, .995).$ You seek $P(W > 2) = P(W > 2.5).$ It is best
to use the latter--for the 'continuity correction'.

```
 1 - pnorm(2.5, 1, sqrt(.99))
 ## 0.06583401
```

If you are instructed to use an approximation for this particular exercise, the Poisson approximation is indeed better than the normal. (But there are instances where the normal is better.) I agree with @DavidQuinn and @Brandon that the Poisson approximation is best and probably what was intended. Also with
@Thanissis that, in serious work, one should not use approximations when exact values are
readily available.

Here is a figure that compares the three distributions for relevant values.
Blue bars show $Binom(100, .01)$ and purple circles the approximating Poisson
values. The 'best fitting' normal density is shown as a green curve; the
relevant area is to the left of the vertical red dotted line. (Much of that
area is to the left of 0.)

[image]